# how to find a user from a user-article table where not even one of his article is in an array of article

Tags: sql

i have an sql table user_article with fields user and article and want to find those user which have not even one of the article in a given array

```
| user | article |
|  --- |   ---   |
|   1  |    52   |    
|   1  |   104   |
|   2  |    12   |    
|   3  |     5   |
|   3  |     4   |
```

given array of article (3,4,52)so i want to have only user 2

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a CTE to see if the article is in the array, then sum the values in the flag and got only users with `sum(flag) = 0`

```
WITH FLAGS AS (
SELECT USER 
    , CASE 
            WHEN ARTICLE IN (3,4,52) THEN 1
            ELSE 0 
    END AS FLAG
FROM USER_ARTICLE
) 
SELECT USER
FROM FLAGS
GROUP BY USER
HAVING SUM(FLAG) = 0
```

Comment: thanks, but that returns me user 1 and 3 also becaus they have also article which is not in array, but i want only user which not even has one of the article shown in array

Comment: posted a correct version

Comment: thats what i needed, thank you

Comment: took a while, but finally found out how to accept, thanks once more